# Struggling with Escaping Single Quotes in SQL Query C# QODBC

Tags: c#, sql, select, quotes, double-quotes

I am trying to run a SQL query that includes single quotes. I am using qodbc and when I have tried to succeed with single quotes by:

1. Using a backslash
2. Using double single quotes

Code:

```
string getQBInventory = "SELECT ListId, Name, QuantityOnHand from Item WHERE Name LIKE '"+ "PMI / 8\"X25''" + "%' AND IncomeAccountRefFullName <> 'Job Income' AND isActive <> 0";
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am querying the following below:

```
PMI/8"X25'
```

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries to avoid such issues.

Comment: Just Tried, Error still occuring. Anything else i can try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. `CommandType` must be `Text`.

```
string getQBInventory = "SELECT ListId, Name, QuantityOnHand from Item WHERE Name LIKE ? AND IncomeAccountRefFullName <> ? AND isActive <> ?"

OdbcCommand exe = new OdbcCommand(getQBInventory, conn);
exe.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

exe.Parameters.Add("P1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "PMI/8\"X25\'\'";
exe.Parameters.Add("P2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "Job Income";
exe.Parameters.Add("P3", OdbcType.Int).Value = 0;
```

Comment: Error: "Unclosed quotation mark after character string 'PMI/8"X25". Incorrect Syntax near 'PMI/8"X25".  Thanks for your help however I got the message above after executing it.

Comment: @TrayvhonMcCall I updated the answer (string value format). Please try again with this value. exe.Parameters.Add("P1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "PMI/8\"X25\'\'";

Comment: Ok  retried now my query is looking for an extra single quote at the end

Comment: I suggest you to use parameters for query because it is more secure. To check any string compatibility with SQL, try to do select statement with string. It will show error in your string. e.g. select 'PMI/8"X25'''

Comment: Kindly upvote / mark as answer if it was useful so future user can take reference from here.

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean. Could you explain it differently? Am I not already using parameters with the code you gave me?

Comment: I think some confusion is there. U said in previous comment that you retired now your query. I though you used the same query mentioned in question so I asked you to use parameters.

Comment: Ok I see. So can you help me solve why It is looking for an extra single quote with the updated code?

Comment: Yes I can. Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up. So if you want add a string with single quote. Place two single quotes. Still got any question?